# Inequatlity for positive functions

Tags: calculus

Let $a \geq 0$, $b \geq 0$, $g \geq 0$. Let $p \geq 1$, $q \geq 1$. Does the following hold:

If $a+b \geq g $ then there exists $C$ independent on $a$ or $b$ such that $a^p+b^q \geq C \min(g^p, g^q)$?

Answer (score 1):

I think we can do it by contradiction. I know that (answer by Surb) $$a^p + b^p \geq C^p (a+b)^p.$$

Now if my claim is not true then for each fixed $g>0$ $\forall i$ exists $a_i$, $b_i$ such that $a_i + b_i \geq g$ and $a_i^p + b_i^q < \frac{1}{i} min(g^p, g^q)$. Putting two inequalities together I obtain
$$\frac{1}{i} > \frac{a_i^p + b_i^q}{(a_i+b_i)^p}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{i} > \frac{a_i^p + b_i^q}{(a_i+b_i)^q}$$
which both must hold.

WLOG $q \geq p$ then if $b_i>1$ we get $b_i^q \geq b_i^p$ and from the first inequality we get $\frac{1}{i} > C^p$ for contradiction.

If $b_i\leq 1$ then if $a_i \leq 1$ then $a_i^p \geq a_i^q$ and from the second inequality we get contradiction.

If $b_i \leq 1$ and $ a_i > 1$ then we use first inequality to get 
$$\frac{1}{i} > \frac{a_i^p + b_i^q}{(a_i+b_i)^p} \geq \frac{a_i^p}{(2a_i)^p} \geq (\frac{1}{2})^p$$
and we have contradiction for i large enough.

Comment: Nice proof :). So, I'll leave my answer for completeness purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote by $\|\cdot\|_p$ the [Minkowski $p$-norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#p-norm).
Wlog let us suppose that $q\geq p$. Since [every norms are equivalent in finite dimensional spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Properties), there exists $C>0$ such that $\|(x,y)\|_p\geq C\|(x,y)\|_1$ for every $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$. Then we get

$$a^p+b^q\geq a^p+b^p = \|(a,b)\|_p^p\geq C^p\|(a,b)\|_1^p=C^p(a+b)^p\geq C^p g^p.$$

Comment: But $b^q \geq b^p$ holds only for $b \geq 1$ and I need this to be true for all possible $a\geq 0$,$b \geq 0$.